# How do I add a buy X get Y free product to cart programmatically with shopping cart rule?

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, programmatically

I have a shopping cart rule, Buy product with SKU XXXXX and get Product with SKU YYYYY discounted. I want to automatically add Y product to cart when X product is added.

**What I've tried**
Creating an observer for updateCartAfter

```
public function updateCartAfter($observer){
```

Getting the Applied rules

```
$appliedRuleIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

Getting the promo SKUs for the rules applied

```
foreach($myrules as $key => $value){
    $promoSkus[$key] = $value['promo_sku'];
}
```

The problem is that my rule is only applied to the shopping cart when the Promo Item (Y) is already in the cart.

I want the rule to be applied when Product X is added so I can pull the promo item(Y) SKU from the rule and add it to the cart automatically.
If there's a better way to do this please let me know.